# How can a custom view determine it's max height/width in a tablerow

Tags: android, view, tablerow

I've got a custom view which I want to show up in a tablerow. Here's what the xml looks like:

```html
.....
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".4">

        <com.blah.MyCustomView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myCustomView"/>
    </TableRow>
.....
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how how much vertical and horizontal space I have to draw on. The canvas.getHeight() and canvas.getWidth from the onDraw(Canvas canvas) is returning the height of the fragment.

How do I figure out the height of the maximum height of a tablerow containing the customView?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` on the View you want.

Comment: Actually it does answer it (or at least makes a good attempt).

Comment: calling getMeasuredWidth()/getMeasuredHeight() on the custom view returns the height/width of the fragment not the tablerow - and the view does not respect the bounds of the tablerow which it is supposed to be contained within.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the size of the fragment because android_width and android_height are set to match_parent and to fill_parent in your XML layout. Try to change all to wrap_content.
fill_parent although it does work, is deprecated. Try to use match_parent from now on.